# Prevent text/screen blinking when doing clear

Tags: bash

My script doing something like:

```
while :;
   clear

   do_a_lot_of_output_here

   sleep 1
done
```

Is it any options to prevent screen of blinking when I'm doing clear and output? I want to do it like in `watch` command (but it's written in `C`). Any advices?

`clear | hexdump -C`

```
00000000  1b 5b 48 1b 5b 32 4a                              |.[H.[2J|
00000007
```

PS. I'm using `bash` only.

Comment: Can you add the output of your `clear | hexdump -C`?

Comment: I've expand the question.

Comment: I found another solution on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5367068/clear-the-ubuntu-bash-screen-for-real - does `echo -en "\ec"` flash too?

Comment: I found this one too. Both variants from answer flash too.

Comment: I had success with this tool: https://excess.org/article/2009/07/watch1-bash-unicode/

Comment: Still top result in google, but for me the solution in a loop was to use a control code of `\033[2K` which will erase the current line.. All i had to do was prepend it to my print statement. This way you only clear a line before you write to it.. Works well in some situations.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The flashing occurs because the script clears the entire screen.  If it paints over the existing text and clears only as necessary, then there will be no flickering.

Here is an example:

```
#!/bin/sh
watchit() {
    HOME=$(tput cup 0 0)
    ED=$(tput ed)
    EL=$(tput el)
    ROWS=$(tput lines)
    COLS=$(tput cols)
    printf '%s%s' "$HOME" "$ED"
    while true
    do
        CMD="$@"
        ${SHELL:=sh} -c "$CMD" | head -n $ROWS | while IFS= read LINE; do
            printf '%-*.*s%s\n' $COLS $COLS "$LINE" "$EL"
        done
        printf '%s%s' "$ED" "$HOME"
        sleep 1
    done
}

watchit top -b -n 1
```

It does this:

- prints the output from the given command that will fit on the screen (no wrapping or scrolling)
- writes over existing lines, clearing the portion of each line which is not overwritten
- uses the `ed` capability of your terminal to print from the current location to the end of the screen.

If you wanted to handle a resizable screen, you could move the assignments to `ROWS` and `COLS` inside the outer loop, e.g.,

```
#!/bin/sh
watchit() {
    HOME=$(tput cup 0 0)
    ED=$(tput ed)
    EL=$(tput el)
    printf '%s%s' "$HOME" "$ED"
    while true
    do
        ROWS=$(tput lines)
        COLS=$(tput cols)
        CMD="$@"
        ${SHELL:=sh} -c "$CMD" | head -n $ROWS | while IFS= read LINE; do
            printf '%-*.*s%s\n' $COLS $COLS "$LINE" "$EL"
        done
        printf '%s%s' "$ED" "$HOME"
        sleep 1
    done
}

watchit top -b -n 1
```

because `tput` asks for the current screensize from the system.

Further reading:

- [**`terminfo`** - *terminal capability data base*](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/terminfo.5.html)
- [**`tput`**,  **`reset`**  -  *initialize  a  terminal or query terminfo database*](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/tput.1.html)

Comment: For those who use `#!/bin/bash` and wish to use `watchit` embedded in a small stand-alone script with some functions, you can do `export -f function_name; watchit function_name`.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me except that I ran into funny issues at the top of the screen, where things would shift and get glitchy for longer chunks of text (anything getting shortened by `head`). Seems the issue is an off-by-one error (at least in my setup -- ssh session in split panes, iTerm2) when computing the number of rows. `ROWS=\`expr $(tput lines) - 1\`` addressed this perfectly.

Comment: This is wonderful, thank you very much @thomas-dickey.

Answer (score 16):

One way to help prevent flashing is to get all the output before clearing the screen so that there is a minimum amount of time between clearing and redrawing it. This is similar to the concept of double buffering:

```
while :; do
   output=$(do_a_lot_of_output_here)
   clear
   echo "$output"
   sleep 1
done
```

This does not completely eliminate the flicker, but it happens significantly less frequently in my experience.

Comment: Double buffering, just like in any other situation, safes the day :-)

Comment: Worked like a charm. No flickering at all :)

Comment: The remaining flickering can be eliminated by including the `clear` into the buffer, i.e. `output=$(clear; do_a_lot_of_output_here)`.

Comment: @kdb Nice suggestion! This almost completely eliminates flickering for me and is much simpler than the accepted answer.

Comment: This works like a charm!

At first I missed the double quotes in the 'echo "$output"', and then the lines get all muddled up. (All whitespaces are considered single spaces.)

Comment: Can anyone explain why putting clear into the output works / helps here? As in kdb's suggestion?

`output=$(clear; do_a_lot_of_output_here)`

I would have thought clear would be run here before calling `do_a_lot_of_output_here`, which makes me thing it would cause a longer delay between clearing and outputting the buffer.

Whereas I would expect clear before the echo would cause the shortest delay?

Comment: Ah, clear just writes to stdout to clear the terminal, so we're just writing that sequence into the buffer before outputting. Very clever. `clear | xxd` -> `00000000: 1b5b 481b 5b32 4a                        .[H.[2J`.

Answer (score 8):

The flashing is an unavoidable result of clearing the screen each time around the loop. You can move the cursor to the top of the screen and overwrite parts of your old output instead.

```
# You may want to do this if your code is in a script.
unhide_cursor() {
    printf '\e[?25h'
}
trap unhide_cursor EXIT

# Hide the cursor (there is probably a much better way to do this)
printf '\e[?25l'
clear 
while true ; do
    # Move the cursor to the top of the screen but don't clear the screen
    printf '\033[;H' 
    do_a_lot_of_output_here
    sleep 1
done
```

This script will leave artifacts if your output shrinks. It's also not very likely to be portable. I've only tested it with urxvt, xterm, and st.

Comment: In this case cursor starts jumping to the end of output from random position (and artifacts of course).  Also I tried `tput clear` with the same results (blinking)

Comment: I added a couple of lines to the script to hide the cursor.

Comment: No cursor - no jumping. But about artifacts? Output has a random amount of rows. Do I need to fill all script with spaces before starting new output? But, anyway, thanks for your time and efforts: +1 from me for that but it doesn't solve my issue

Comment: I found only one way to get rid of all artifacts: `tput ed`. But it cause blinking

Comment: What terminal emulator are you using? With `tput ed` right before the `do_a_lot...` line, I'm seeing blinking in urxvt but not xterm or st.

Comment: I'm using xterm.

Answer (score 1):

As an extension of Cristian's answer, I made the following bash function which works if the console window is smaller than the output of the command:

```
function watcher()
{
    lines=$(tput lines)
    while true; do
        output="$($@ | head -n $lines)"
        clear
        echo -e "$output"
        sleep 2
    done
}
```

This allows you to pass any command to the watcher. If you are using git, use `git config --global color.status always` and then:

```
watcher git status
```

Will display an always-updating git status output.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on if you have one line or multiple lines. tput isn't an bad option but I like using esc codes...

```
while true
do
    printf "^[[H^[[0K$do_a_lot_of_output"
    sleep 0.01
done
```

**^[[H** moves the cursor to 0,0 or the top left corner and ^[[0K erases from the current cursor position to the end of the line.

**^[[0K** is nice because it will clear the line from the current cursor position to the end of line and wouldn't see any residual data if the next string happens to be shorter than the previous string

one example is if $do_a_lot_of_output = 20 during the first iteration and then $do_a_lot_of_output = 5 on the second the output would be 50. If you didn't include ^[[0K since it's only going to output as far as it has to, the 2 in 20 gets overwritten with the new 5 but the 0 remains giving you a misleading 50.

I think ^[[K can be used as well

Start an esc code sequence by pressing ctrl+v then ESC to produce ^[
then add another [ + the code in this case H or K

you put it all together to get ^[[H or ^[[K

list of Ansi escape codes:
https://gist.github.com/fnky/458719343aabd01cfb17a3a4f7296797

Comment: `tput` is the portable way of outputting escape codes. It means you don’t need to know the specific codes for whatever output device is being used.

Comment: I agree tput is nice, I just prefer using esc codes for maybe formatting a table or something like 

printf "^[[H$varible_at_home^[[20G^[[K$something_20_columns_away"